# PHP calling an abstract method from within an abstract method

Tags: php

If you have something like the following:

```
abstract class User {

    function checkThis() {          

        return true;    
    }

    function mainFunction() {

    }
}
```

and you want to call `checkThis()` from within `mainFunction()`, would you do it like this?

```
abstract class User {

    function checkThis() {

        return true;    
    }

    function mainFunction() {

        if ($this->checkThis())
            echo "Works";
    }
```

I seem to be having problems if I call this from within another class, say:

```
class SecondClass {

    function test() {
        User::mainFunction();
    }    
}
```

Provides this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method SecondClass::checkThis()
```

Comment: What problem are you having? Is there an error message?

Comment: You want to call a function from a static context within the same class. This works if you use `self::checkThis()` instead of `$this->checkThis()`

Comment: Another problem here is that it seems that you don't close the class user, it misses an `}`

Comment: @Lex are there any negatives of using `self::`, not bad practise?

Comment: @Silver89: Well not really. However in `SecondClass()` write `$this->mainFunction()` instead of `User::mainFunction()`. It's not a static function you call, so use `$this`. Also extend from the base-type, it looks you've forgotten that: `class SecondClass extends User`.

Comment: Consider `static::` above `self::` for late bindings.

Comment: No, consider objects methods over class functions for real work.

Comment: can you please update the question with more concrete code because your example code makes it rather to understand why the purpose of all this is.

Comment: An one final hint: It works as announced in the PHP manual. I've never seen this (what is written in question title) a problem in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

You should maybe consider having a class you can instantiate which extends this abstract class. e.g.

```
class userConcrete extends User {

}
```

Then in second class you can inject the user object like so:

```
class SecondClass{

    protected $user;

    public function __construct(userConcrete $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }
    function test(){
        $this->user->mainFunction();
    }

}
```

Also making mainFunction public in your abstract class.